# Graphing different sets of data on same graph within a ‘for’ loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, regression

I just have a problem with graphing different plots on the same graph within a ‘for’ loop. I hope someone can be point me in the right direction.

I have a 2-D array, with discrete chunks of data in and amongst zeros. My data is the following:

A=

```
    0           0
    0           0
    0           0
    3           9
    4          10
    5          11
    6          12
    0           0
    0           0
    0           0
    0           0
    7         9.7
    8         9.8
    9         9.9
    0           0
    0       0
```

A chunk of data is defined as contiguous set of data, without interruptions of a [0 0] row. So in this example, the 1st chunk of data would be

```
    3           9
    4          10
    5          11
    6          12
```

And 2nd chunk is

```
    7        9.7
    8        9.8
    9        9.9
```

The first column is x and second column is y. I would like to plot y as a function of x (x is horizontal axis, y is vertical axis) I want to plot these data sets on the same graph as a scatter graph, and put a line of best fit through the points, whenever I come across a chunk of data. In this case, I will have 2 sets of points and 2 lines of best fit (because I have 2 chunks of data). I would also like to calculate the R-squared value

The code that I have so far is shown below:

```
fh1 = figure;
hold all;
ah1 = gca;

% plot graphs:
for d = 1:max_number_zeros+num_rows
    if sequence_holder(d,1)==0
        continue;
    end
    c = d;

    while sequence_holder(c,1)~=0
        plot(ah1,sequence_holder(c,1),sequence_holder(c,num_cols),'*');
        %lsline;
        c =c+1;
        continue;
    end
end
```

Sequence holder is the array with the data in it. I can only plot the first set of data, with no line of best fit. I tried lsline, but that didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to

-plot both sets of graphs

-how to draw a line of best fit a get the regression coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part could be done in a number of ways. I would test the second column for zeroness

```
zerodata = A(:,2) == 0;
```

which will give you a logical array of ones and zeros like [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...]. Then you can use this to split up your input. You could look at the `diff` of that array and test it for positive or negative sign. Your data starts on 0 so you won't get a transition for that one, so you'd need to think of some way to deal with that or the opposite case, unless you know for certain that it will always be one way or the other. You could just test the first element, or you could insert a known value at the start of your input array.

You will then have to store your chunks. As they may be of variable length and variable number you wouldn't put them into a big matrix, but you still want to be able to use a loop. I would use either a cell array, where each cell in a row contains the x or y data for a chunk, or a struct array where say `structarray(1).x` and `structarray)1).y` hold your data values.

Then you can iterate through your struct array and call plot on each chunk separately.

As for fitting you can use the `fit` command. It's complex and has lots of options so you should check out the help first (type `doc fit` inside the console to get the inline help, which is the same as the website help in content). The short version is that you can do a simple linear fit like this

```
[fitobject, gof] = fit(x, y, 'poly1');
```

where 'poly1' specifies you want a first order polynomial (i.e. straight line) and the output arguments give you a fit object, which you can do various things with like plot or interpolate, and the second gives you a struct containing among other things the r^2 and adjusted r^2. The fitobject also contains your fit coefficients.